# Image doesn't display in Web page in case of image name contain any special character

Tags: html

I need show image from folder to web page. **image not dispay in case of image name contains any of special character**.I need to display image **without rename**.

Comment: what is the name of the file, and what is the source of the image tag, or the code which is producing it if it's dynamic?

Comment: is it possible for you to share the a image name for same?

Comment: @KamranSohail  image name-" IMG_20180115_121912#.jpg"

Comment: I have placed the answer for you

Comment: `#` is the URL *fragment*, has a special meaning, and causes `#.jpg` not to be sent to the server at all.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use encodeurl() below is the sample which will help you.

```
<?php
$imgname = urlencode("MG_20180115_121912#.jpg");
?>
<img src="<?php echo $imgname;?>" />
```

Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Kamran's Answer is if you have control over sever side code. If not then following is the front End code for the same.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img src="MG_20180115_121912#.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42">
<script>
;(function(){
    const imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for(let ix=0,len=imgs.length;ix<len;ix++){
        let img = imgs[ix];
        let src = encodeURIComponent(img.attributes.src.nodeValue);
            img.src = src;
    }
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```